# Pass String with Xpand method call as parameter

Tags: java, xpand

In XPAND template, I have a call where, the call should be done for the method which takes the String and the Object.

i.e. ,

```
«setData("String",Object)-»
```

For the above method, the String value I want to pass is the simplified value of below string:
where ,`«getAddress(object)»` , return dynamic value.

`"/begin DATA XETK DEFAULT_RASTERS  «getAddress(object)»  /end DATA"`

If I try to do this in the below way, i get compilation error.

```
«setData("/begin DATA XETK DEFAULT_RASTERS  «getAddress(object)»  /end DATA",Object)-»
```

Can anyone help me, how can I pass this string to the method?

Thanks ,

Regards,
Shwetha

Answer (score 0):

Ok  , I got the answer for the above question.

In XPAND , the expressions are not allowed to pass as parameter. But this is done in XTEND 2